# Docker Install - Transaction check error:

Tags: linux, docker, centos

When i'm trying to install docker to my CentOS VPS, I get thise error

```
 Transaction check error:
   file /usr/bin/docker from install of docker-ce-18.04.0.ce-3.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-common-2:1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64
   file /usr/bin/docker-containerd from install of docker-ce-18.04.0.ce-3.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-common-2:1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64
   file /usr/bin/docker-containerd-shim from install of docker-ce-18.04.0.ce-3.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-common-2:1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64
   file /usr/bin/dockerd from install of docker-ce-18.04.0.ce-3.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-common-2:1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64

 Error Summary
 -------------
```

Comment: im gonna retry and post the whole process

Comment: https://hastebin.com/hocecibega.makefile